# javascript convert distinguished name into domain

Tags: javascript, arrays, active-directory

Need to change distinguished names to a domain

distinguished names:
CN=Dan Adam,OU=testUsers,DC=KALK,DC=DTC
convert to KALK.DTC

So whatever comes in "DC" part is joined using "." i.e., "KALK.DTC"

Need to convert DN to a domain
CN=Dan Adam,OU=testUsers,DC=KALK,DC=DTC

into "KALK.DTC"

```
const dn='CN=Dan Adam,OU=testUsers,DC=KALK,DC=DTC'
   let element=[];
        const parts = dn.split(',');
                 
                    for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                        let p = parts[i]
                         element = p.split('=');
                    }
                    const dom= element.join('.')
                    console.log(dom)
```

Also what do I do if given an array of DNs and need to convert them to an array of domains?

Answer (score 2):

Quick approach using two loops, [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const dn = "CN=Dan Adam,OU=testUsers,DC=KALK,DC=DTC";

let res = dn.split(",")
    .filter(e => e.startsWith("DC="))
    .map(e => e.substring(3))
    .join(".");

console.log(res);
```

---

Even lazyer approach using one loop only, [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (basically `filter` and `map` combined in a single function):

```js
const dn = "CN=Dan Adam,OU=testUsers,DC=KALK,DC=DTC";

let res = dn.split(",")
    .flatMap(e => e.startsWith("DC=") ? e.substring(3) : [])
    .join(".");

console.log(res);
```

---

If your input is an array of dn's and you expext a single sting as output, you can just join it. Both of the solutions I wrote, extract all `DC`'s:

```js
const dn = ["CN=Dan Adam,OU=testUsers,DC=KALK,DC=DTC", "CN=Clark Smith,OU=testUsers,DC=FUN,DC=DTC"];

let res = dn.join(",").split(",")
    .flatMap(e => e.startsWith("DC=") ? e.substring(3) : [])
    .join(".");
    
console.log(res);
```

---

If you want to keep the items split up, just map the original array. Again, both solutions can work with that:

```js
const dn = ["CN=Dan Adam,OU=testUsers,DC=KALK,DC=DTC", "CN=Clark Smith,OU=testUsers,DC=FUN,DC=DTC"];

let res = dn.map(item => item.split(",")
    .flatMap(e => e.startsWith("DC=") ? e.substring(3) : [])
    .join(".")
);
    
console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks, what do I do if given a list of DNs ?
dn = ["CN=Dan Adam,OU=testUsers,DC=KALK,DC=DTC", "CN=Clark Smith,OU=testUsers,DC=FUN,DC=DTC"];

Comment: appreciate that. Is there a way if given a domain such as KALK.DTC to check if it exist in the list of DNs? dn = ["CN=Dan Adam,OU=testUsers,DC=KALK,DC=DTC", "CN=Clark Smith,OU=testUsers,DC=FUN,DC=DTC"]; ?

Comment: @ddark13 This is getting a bit out of scope since that's an entirely different question than the one you posted. But yes, using Array#includes: [see demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/bkhor9wm/). If my answer did indeed solve your original question, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it :)